# JSON exception in cakephp 3

Tags: json, exception, cakephp-3.0, httpresponse

I'm doing a restfull api in cakephp...
And sometime i have some throw exceptions. For example:

```
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException("The requested resource does not support http method " . $this->request->param('_method'));
        }
```

My problem is when the url is /controller/action.json the response is :

```
{
message: "The requested resource does not support http method GET",
url: "/api/auth/users/authenticate.json",
code: 405
}
```

In json format, but, when my url is /controller/action. My response is HTML, i want to know if is possible to force these exceptions to be always json without putting .json in the url.

Thanks!

Comment: You could specify `application/json` in the response header.

Comment: You can use `$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');`

Comment: I add that to my action in the controller before throw the exception... but without success... The exception is render as HTML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force exceptions to be always rendered in json adding in **Controller/ErrorController.php** (in `beforeRender`)

```php
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: But wouldn't placing this into *Controller/ErrorController.php* affect all errors, including those where you don't need a JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

In the action do the following. As suggested in the notes.

```
if (!$this->request->is('post')) {
    $this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException("The requested resource does not support http method " . $this->request->param('_method'));
}
```

For this to work you will need the component too.

```
public function initialize() {
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

Comment: Yes, i do that in my controller... but is still rendering as HTML.. i don't know why...

Comment: @jaloise Ill try a few more things when I get home as I believe I have had this working before. You could also write the response object directly `$this->response` yourself instead of throwing the error and letting Cake handle it.

Comment: i try that without success.